# Haskell kind system vs type families and multi param type classes

Tags: haskell, type-kinds

In Haskell I find it difficult to completely grasp the purpose of a kind system, and what it truly adds to the language.

I understand having kinds adds safety.
For example consider `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` vs a monokinded version of it `fmap2 :: (a -> b) -> p -> q`.

My understanding is that, thanks to the kind system, I can specify beforehand with higher detail what the shape of the data should be. It is better, as the type checker can check more, and stricter requirements will make it less likely that users will mess up with types. This will reduce the likelihood of programming errors. I believe this is the main motivation for kinds but I might be wrong.

Now I think fmap2 can have the same implementation as fmap, since its types are unconstrained. Is it true?

Could one just replace all multi kinded types in the base/ghc library by mono kinded ones, and would it still compile correctly?

To clarify a little bit I mean that for a class like:

```hs
class  Functor f  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
```

I might replace it by something like

```hs
class  Functor a b p q  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> p -> q
    (<$)        :: a -> q -> p
```

This way for a `Functor` instance like

```hs
instance Functor [] where fmap = map
```

I might replace it by

```hs
instance Functor a b p q where fmap = map
```

Remark: This wont work as is because i also need to modify `map` and go down the dependency chain. Will think more about this later..

I'm trying to figure out if kinds add more than just safety? Can I do something with multi kinded types that I cannot do with mono kinded ones?

Remark: Here I forgot to mention i'm usually using some language extensions, typically to allow more flexibility in writing classes.
When doing vanilla haskell kinds can be really meaningful thing to use.
But when I start using type families, and a few of other extensions it becomes much less clear that I need kinds at all.

I have in mind that there is some monotraversable library which reimplements many  standard library functions using single kinded types, and type families to generalize signatures. That's why my intuition is that multi kinded variables might not really add that much expressive power after all, provided one uses type families. However a drawback of doing this is that you lose type safety. My question is do you really only lose just that, or do you really lose something else.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, so am I correct that fmap2 is strictly more general than fmap and its implementation could be identical?

Comment: Im not an expert of type theory, i've been looking at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)   but I find it hard to understand the deep underlying reason why this whole kind system really exist

Comment: As there is type based function level programming, there is kind based type level  programming and perhaps even a sort based kind level programming might exist in the future. [Types and Kinds and Sorts, Oh My!](https://jozefg.bitbucket.io/posts/2014-02-10-types-kinds-and-sorts.html) is a good read.

Comment: @J.M. you are not correct about that.  It is more general, but it cannot be implemented.

Comment: The complete type of `fmap` is actually longer than what you say in your question: `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. How would you state the constraint analogous to `Functor f` for your proposed alternative type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463811/any-advantage-of-using-type-constructors-in-type-classes has a couple answers that cover some advantages of the higher-kinded formulation, in both practical and theoretical terms. It also has an example of when it can be useful to give up those advantages for new capabilities.

Comment: If nothing else, standard Haskell supports a kind system, but not multiparameter type classes.

Answer (score 5):

Let's back up.  It seems like you think that because the signature

```
id2 :: a -> b
```

is more general than

```
id :: a -> a
```

that `id2` could have the same implementation as `id`.  But that's not true.  In fact `id2` has no total implementation (any implementation of `id2` involves an infinite loop or `undefined`).

The structure of generality creates a "pressure", and this pressure is what we must navigate to find the right type for something.  If `f` is more general than `g`, that means that *anywhere `g` could be used, `f` could also* but it **also** means that *any implementation of `f` is a valid implementation of `g`*.  So at the use site it goes one direction, at the definition site it goes the other.

We can use `id2` anywhere we could have used `id`, but the signature of `id2` is so general that it is impossible to implement.  The more general a signature gets, the more contexts it can be used in, but also the less likely it is to have an implementation.  I would say a main goal of a good type signature is to find the level of generality where there are *as few as possible* implementations of your intended function, without making it impossible to write altogether.

Your proposed signature `fmap2 :: (a -> b) -> p -> q` is, like `id2`, so general that it is impossible to implement.  The purpose of higher-kinded types is to give us the tools to have very general signatures like `fmap`, which are not *too* general like `fmap2`.

Comment: To be fair, the proposed type `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` from the question is also impossible to implement. (And this is not the type that `fmap` has in Haskell.) So one might want to first figure out what context the OP has in mind for `fmap2`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, true.  This answer was quite a struggle to write, I have to cover too much ground at once.  I want to see how OP responds and take from there...

Comment: Completely fair. I started writing an answer, too, and struggled for a similar reason.

Comment: @luqui What about if I use type families: ```type family ElemOf x :: *``` Can't I implement ```fmap3 :: (ElemOf p -> ElemOf q) -> p -> q```?

Comment: @luqi OK so if I have this:
```
class AAA a b where id2 :: a -> b
```
nothing prevents me from doing this
```
instance AAA a a where id2 = id
```
Right?
Similarly instead of having this:
```
class  Functor f  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```
I could have this
```
class  Functor a b p q  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> p -> q
```
OK i'm adding parameters but I can keep the same code for each Functor instance no?

Comment: @J.M., oh ok I am starting to see what you are asking.  It might be instructive to attempt these sorts of definitions and then try to use them.  Redo a bit of the standard library in your style, perhaps. Just make sure you don't stop at "the definition type checks" -- the mechanics at the use site come into play also.

Comment: Ive looked at that monotraversable library which sort of avoids kinds. see what i mean? thats why im confused as to what is the true purpose of kinds beside safety..